# Is there a way to disable the "Use a device" option in the Windows 10 Boot Manager?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I am trying to prevent resetting my PC and using other devices to boot from my machine. I've already disabled using these devices from the BIOS but have noticed that it's still possible by using the Windows Boot Manager on the two screens below. Is it possible to disable these screens?[image]

[image]

Comment: This is your life rope.

Comment: Absolutely true but I am working in a high security environment where I dont want people booting to os's installed on a cd/other media or resetting whats currently installed on the machine. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That screen is the program bootim.exe.  A GPO to restrict software should stop it from running, as well as a black list for that exe in local gpedit.

You can also create a registry entry that will stop it from running. This is the powershell to do it.

New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\bootim.exe"

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\bootim.exe" -Name "Debugger" -Type "String" -Value "taskill /F /IM bootim.exe" -Force

I've been searching for a while, this is all I've found.